# Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Ng4MaskModule

Tags: angular

I installed ng4-mask package and imported Ng4MaskModule into `info.component.ts`

Then I tried to run npm start, but I'm receiving the error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 13:36 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol Ng4MaskModule

I'm using ng-version: 4.4.7

info.component.ts

```js
import { Ng4MaskModule } from 'ng4-mask';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        Ng4MaskModule.forRoot(),
      ],
declarations: [  ],
  providers: [  ],
})
export class InfoModule { }
```

Comment: This is the module or the component (you say it is info.component.ts)? I think it's your module, in which case you should need an exports array with the component name in it.

Comment: you should include `.forRoot()` in your root module only, which is app.module

Comment: Removed .forRoot() from info.module.ts and included in app.module, but still getting the same error for the first time. If I save anything and refresh then compilation is successful.

Comment: @rrd -- Sry its info.module.ts file only. Can you plz elaborate your answer. Thanks